# android get application context from anywhere but its always show class cast exeption i dont knoew how to use

Tags: android

```
    i just get references from net and update code in android.means get application context from anywhere.but its always show class cast exeption i dont knoew how to use in adapter/activity,fragments 
    please anyone know about this share your view/thoughts

    Applicationcontext.java
        package com.example.admin.myapplication;

        import android.app.Application;
        import android.content.Context;

        import com.example.admin.myapplication.models.ParsedApplicationSettings;

        public class ApplicationContext extends Application {

            /**
             * The settings obtained after parsing the XML file
             */
            public ParsedApplicationSettings mParsedApplicationSettings = null;
            private static Context context;

            public ParsedApplicationSettings getParsedApplicationSettings() {
                return mParsedApplicationSettings;
            }

            /**
             * Setter for ParsedApplicationSettings
             * 
             * @param parsedApplicationSettings
             *            the parsed XML settings to set for the applicationContext;
             */
            public void setParsedApplicationSettings(
                    ParsedApplicationSettings parsedApplicationSettings) {
                this.mParsedApplicationSettings = parsedApplicationSettings;
            }

        }

    Mainactivity.java
    basically in this activity i have implement navigation drawer. i used entire application context to single state class.but whenever i use that application context always show classcast exception,nullpointer execption
    package com.example.admin.myapplication.fragments;
    i use get this code from net and i dont have 2 much knoewlage about android deep
basically in this activity i have implement navigation drawer. i used entire application context to single state class.but whenever i use that application context always show classcast exception,nullpointer execption
    package com.example.admin.myapplication.fragments;
    i use get this code from net and i dont have 2 much knoewlage about android deep
...sorry for poor english

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    import com.example.admin.myapplication.ApplicationContext;
    import com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity;
    import com.example.admin.myapplication.R;
    import com.example.admin.myapplication.adapters.HomeFragmentViewPagerAdapter;
    import com.example.admin.myapplication.models.MainPageSettings;


    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

        public static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        public interface ActionListener {
            void onReservationButtonClicked();

            void onRatesButtonClicked();

            void onGalleryButtonClicked();

            void onRoomsButtonClicked();

            void onFacilitiesButtonClicked();

            void onLocationsButtonClicked();
        }

        private android.support.v4.view.ViewPager mViewPager;

        private RelativeLayout mReservationButton;
        private RelativeLayout mRatesButton;
        private RelativeLayout mGalleryButton;
        private RelativeLayout mRoomsButton;
        private RelativeLayout mFacilitiesButton;
        private RelativeLayout mLocationsButton;

        private ActionListener mActionListener;

        private ApplicationContext mAppContext=new ApplicationContext();

        public HomeFragment() {
            super();
        }

        public static HomeFragment newInstance(ApplicationContext appContext,
                ActionListener actionListener) {

            if (actionListener == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(ActionListener.class.getName()
                        + " is null!");
            }
            HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
            fragment.mActionListener = actionListener;
            fragment.mAppContext = appContext;
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPager);

            MainPageSettings mainPageSettings = mAppContext
                    .getParsedApplicationSettings().getMainPageSettings();

            HomeFragmentViewPagerAdapter adapter = new HomeFragmentViewPagerAdapter(
                    mAppContext, mainPageSettings.getMainPreviewPictures());
            mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    //
    //      CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view
    //              .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPagerBullets);
    //      circleIndicator.setRadius(MainActivity.dipsToPixels(mAppContext, 8));
    //      circleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

            ImageView rightButton = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPagerRightButton);
            rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mViewPager.getAdapter() != null
                            && mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() > mViewPager
                                    .getCurrentItem()) {
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                    }
                }
            });

            ImageView leftButton = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPagerLeftButton);

            leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mViewPager.getAdapter() != null
                            && mViewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                    }
                }
            });

            if (mViewPager.getAdapter() != null
                    && mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() < 2) {
                leftButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rightButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                leftButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rightButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            mReservationButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerFirstRowReservationButton);
            mReservationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mActionListener.onReservationButtonClicked();
                }
            });
            mRoomsButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerFirstRowRoomsButton);
            mRoomsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mActionListener.onRoomsButtonClicked();
                }
            });

            mRatesButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerSecondRowRatesButton);
            mRatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mActionListener.onRatesButtonClicked();
                }
            });

            mFacilitiesButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerSecondRowFacilitiesButton);
            mFacilitiesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mActionListener.onFacilitiesButtonClicked();
                }
            });

            mGalleryButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerThirdRowGalleryButton);
            mGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mActionListener.onGalleryButtonClicked();
                }
            });

            mLocationsButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerThirdRowLocationsButton);
            mLocationsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    mActionListener.onLocationsButtonClicked();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
    }


        locat
        this module showing error of code that is occuring after execution of application
         java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.admin.myapplication/com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.admin.myapplication.ApplicationContext
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
                                                          Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.example.admin.myapplication.ApplicationContext
                                                             at com.example.admin.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                             at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
                                                             at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 


Home_fragment.java(fragment)
this is the first fragment of slider menu which is showing on the top viewpager and in bottom menus(rooms,reservation.....).viewpager slide images whenever user click on menus show particular fragment
all menus are fragments,
```

i dont know why this kind of error occur.i define all instance pass properly
please sir chcek
    this is the first fragment of slider menu which is showing on the top viewpager and in bottom menus(rooms,reservation.....).viewpager slide images whenever user click on menus show particular fragment
    all menus are fragments,
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
    public static final String TAG = HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    public interface ActionListener {
        void onReservationButtonClicked();

        void onRatesButtonClicked();

        void onGalleryButtonClicked();

        void onRoomsButtonClicked();

        void onFacilitiesButtonClicked();

        void onLocationsButtonClicked();
    }

    private android.support.v4.view.ViewPager mViewPager;

    private RelativeLayout mReservationButton;
    private RelativeLayout mRatesButton;
    private RelativeLayout mGalleryButton;
    private RelativeLayout mRoomsButton;
    private RelativeLayout mFacilitiesButton;
    private RelativeLayout mLocationsButton;

    private ActionListener mActionListener;

    private ApplicationContext mAppContext;

    public HomeFragment() {
        super();
    }

    public static HomeFragment newInstance(ApplicationContext appContext,
            ActionListener actionListener) {

        if (actionListener == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(ActionListener.class.getName()
                    + " is null!");
        }
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        fragment.mActionListener = actionListener;
        fragment.mAppContext = appContext;
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPager);
//
        MainPageSettings mainPageSettings = mAppContext
                .getParsedApplicationSettings().getMainPageSettings();
        HomeFragmentViewPagerAdapter adapter = new HomeFragmentViewPagerAdapter(
                mAppContext, mainPageSettings.getMainPreviewPictures());
        mViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPagerBullets);
        circleIndicator.setRadius(MainActivity.dipsToPixels(mAppContext, 8));
        circleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        ImageView rightButton = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPagerRightButton);
        rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                if (mViewPager.getAdapter() != null
                        && mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() > mViewPager
                                .getCurrentItem())
                {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
                }
            }
        });

        ImageView leftButton = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentViewPagerLeftButton);

        leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mViewPager.getAdapter() != null
                        && mViewPager.getCurrentItem() > 0) {
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mViewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
                }
            }
        });

        if (mViewPager.getAdapter() != null
                && mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() < 2) {
            leftButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rightButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            leftButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            rightButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        mReservationButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerFirstRowReservationButton);
        mReservationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActionListener.onReservationButtonClicked();
            }
        });
        mRoomsButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerFirstRowRoomsButton);
        mRoomsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActionListener.onRoomsButtonClicked();
            }
        });

        mRatesButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerSecondRowRatesButton);
        mRatesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActionListener.onRatesButtonClicked();
            }
        });

        mFacilitiesButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerSecondRowFacilitiesButton);
        mFacilitiesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActionListener.onFacilitiesButtonClicked();
            }
        });

        mGalleryButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerThirdRowGalleryButton);
        mGalleryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActionListener.onGalleryButtonClicked();
            }
        });

        mLocationsButton = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.mainFragmentButtonsContainerThirdRowLocationsButton);
        mLocationsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mActionListener.onLocationsButtonClicked();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
updated second logcat 
this second updqated logcat showing error of home_fragment
that showing error on first fragment
this second updqated logcat showing error of home_fragment
that showing error on first fragment
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.admin.myapplication.models.MainPageSettings com.example.admin.myapplication.models.ParsedApplicationSettings.getMainPageSettings()' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.example.admin.myapplication.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:90)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1234)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2046)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:174)
                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:597)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5949)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you registered you application class in manifest? Whats the code at `MainActivity` line 70?

Comment: i updated code sir please check..regsiter in manifest file

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBamLZiZbqfUWJVYUtoNmpVVGM/view?ts=57a3470a

Comment: pls check and import in android studio......

Comment: i dont know why its happen...pls sir help.........pls sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure you register your `ApplicationContext` in manifest file under `android:name` tag. Secondly, the problem that appears to be with your code is this line:

```
private ApplicationContext mAppContext = new ApplicationContext();
```

Here, you are basically creating a new instance of your application class. This is unnecessary because if your application class is registered in the manifest then it will automatically create an instance of this class. Moreover, I believe you want to do some like having reference of the `context`. Do something like this:

```
private Context mContext;
```

Then, in your `newInstance` get context as follows:

```
public static HomeFragment newInstance(Context context,
            ActionListener actionListener) {
    ...
    mContext = context;
    ...
}
```

You call this method as:

```
HomeFragment.newInstance(getApplicationContext(), listener);
```

Comment: You don't need to create a new application class instance. What error are you talking about?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:219)

Comment: @sumit Can you try adding in your ApplicationContext class '@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

    }'

Comment: @sumit is it working after adding the above code in your application class? If not, then remove the 'accepted tick' from my answer above. Also, I tried to run the code, its in Eclipse and I couldn't compile it straight away. I'm in office so can't debug much.

Comment: ohk sir thank u so much sir whenever u free please debug this code

Comment: not working anyway and can't untick your answer...bcz i'm satisfied with ur answer but whenever u get free please check

Comment: i want to know ur mailid

Comment: @sumit its an Eclipse project and I'm trying to import it in Android Studio which brings up a lot of third party dependencies...which may get quite time consuming for me.

Comment: your answer working for me but in home fragment show error....which mention above code logcat 2...i imort successfully and working but fragments show error becoz of applicationcontext class

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.example.admin.myapplication.models.MainPageSettings com.example.admin.myapplication.models.ParsedApplicationSettings.getMainPageSettings()' on a null object reference
                                                       at com.example.admin.myapplication.fragments.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:96)

Comment: @sumit is anything else printed in the logcat before the error above. Should be an `IOException`

Comment: no sir its nullpointer exeption......occur in homepage fragments...mention above  last 3rd commnt

Comment: @sumit I'm sorry man, without running the code its really difficult to follow program execution flow. I'd suggest you use breakpoints (debug) to pin-point where the error occur if you aren't already.

Comment: done all possible think sir....debug also  this line create error... MainPageSettings mainPageSettings = mAppContext.getParsedApplicationSettings().getMainPageSettings(); 1 mappcontext(Application context cls,2nd one set getter method,3rd one is define ParsedApplicationSettings class which in define getter/setter for all fragments)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to achieve is to set the context on application build as static so you can access it anywhere in the application.

```
public class App extends Application {
    private static final String TAG = PubApp.class.getSimpleName();

    private static App instance;

    public static Context getAppContext(){
        return  instance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

And you have to register the application class in the manifest `<application>` element.

```
<application
android:name=".App"
...
</application>
```

Comment: Thats almost always a bad idea

Comment: @Shaishav, yes, but no-one can explain why because it always works fine (with rare exceptions of apps having background threads surviving the app, which might be a leak). So, it is a good idea.

Comment: @EugeneKartoyev agree, app instance is implicitly leaked, but since it's guaranteed singleton no way this can lead to any memory leak issues. Also, any class within the app should have a valid context instance too. I wrote that comment several years back - I was wrong then.